# CodeIgniter is not redirecting properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to implement basic section that only a logged-in user can access. I overrided CI_Controller, as follow:

```
//file created in application/core/MY_Controller.php
class Auth_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');

        if ($this->session->userdata('user_logged') !== null){
            redirect(base_url() . 'dashboard');
            die();
        } else {
            redirect(base_url() . 'auth/login');
            die();
        }
    }
```

And then I extend from Auth_Controller all the other controllers that are only available for the logged-in user, as follow:

```
class Dashboard extends Auth_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboardView');
    }
}
```

But after the login is successful, it doesn't redirect to dashboardView.

Anyone knows what is really happening?

Comment: By "not redirect to dashboardView" what do you mean exactly? does it show a white page? redirect to another page?

Comment: If I used another another view  I get the same issue. The browser shows: "The page isn’t redirecting properly"

Comment: Only the first letter of the controller should be upper case on filename and class name explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redirecting infinitely to the `Dashboard` controller in this part of the code:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('user_logged') !== null){
    redirect(base_url() . 'dashboard');
    die();
}
```

Use this instead (redirect to the login form if the user is not logged in):

```
class Auth_controller extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('session');

        // If the user is not logged in
        if ($this->session->userdata('user_logged') === null){
            // Redirect to http://yoursite/auth/login
            // No need for the base_url function, redirect does it for you
            redirect('auth/login'); 
            // You don't have to exit/die, redirect() already does that
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be $this->session->userdata('user_logged') !== null to redirect to dashboard, isn't it?

Comment: We check if the user is not logged in, if so, we redirect to the dashboard, if he is already logged in we do nothing and continue executing the rest of the Controller, check the updated answer.

Comment: Only the first letter of the controller should be upper case on filename and class name explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Yes, now it has more sense. I took Mehdi's approach, but using $_SESSION for some the session library of CI not work, I tried load in code and autoload, too.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 in this case I should rename MY_Controller.php to My_controller.php, thanks.

Comment: If you are extending controller MY_Controller

Answer (score 0):

**Opinions**

1. If I check the null, will use like this `!= null`. BUT in CI **its a best option to check `empty()` rather `null`**.
2. If I use `redirect()` will use it like this `redirect('dashboard');`

---

**Code will be**

```
if (!empty($this->session->userdata('user_logged'))) {
    redirect('dashboard');
else {
    redirect('auth/login');
}
```

---

> > **Make sure your site will load without `index.php` in URL. If no search for `.htaccess` to your site.**